# Ignore base class properties during auto mapping in ElasticSearch using NEST

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, nest

I'm working on Elastic Search 5.4 and using NEST to create index in C#, When I do a automap for a class which in Inheriting from SortedDictionary, The base class properties like Count,Comparer,Items are added to the Mapping, Can some one please help me how to avoid this.

Thanks

```
 public class Document : SortedDictionary<string, dynamic>
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
 }
```

The actual mapping I'm getting  is

```
{"DocumentMapping": {
"mappings": {
  "Document": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": null,
    "Documents": {
      "properties": {
        "Comparer": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "Count": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Item": {
          "type": "object",
          "include_in_all": false
        },
        "ID": {
          "type": "int "
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

What I need is

```
{"DocumentMapping": {
"mappings": {
  "Document": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": null,
    "Documents": {
      "properties": 
        "ID": {
          "type": "int "
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

How do I ignore the the Comparer,Count and Item from my mapping JSON.

Comment: May you share mapping code?

Comment: @Rob var indexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(Configuration.IndexName)
                                                        .Mappings(ms => ms.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap()
                                                        .Dynamic(new Union<bool, DynamicMapping>(DynamicMapping.Strict))
                                                        .AllField(a => a.Enabled(false))))
                                                        .Aliases(a => a.CopyTo(aliasesDescriptor));

            var createIndexResponse = await Client.CreateIndexAsync(indexDescriptor, cancellationToken);